# Zebra GK420d printing some barcodes fuzzy

Tags: printing, zebra-printers

It looks like the barcode is being dithered. I had a similar problem on another computer. Then, I just turned dithering off. I've done that here as well but the problem persists. Some barcodes print clearly but others that have more characters print fuzzy. They appear fine onscreen and print fine on other printers.

On the one computer, it prints fine so I don't think there's actually anything wrong with the printer, just the settings. I've even tried exporting and importing settings. That doesn't help.

In chrome on the good computer, I hit print and everything works fine. If I use the system dialog print settings, it fails. Even if I just open the preferences and press OK, it will still come out poorly.

Comment: Are you using the printer resident barcode fonts or sending down some windows font that is scaled etc.?

Comment: Whatever it's doing by default. I haven't specified anything.

Answer (score 2):

After beating my head against everything I could think of, all I had to do was turn off the margins from within the print options. Admittedly there are other weird things going on but as long as it will work for what we need, I'm fine with that.

The margins were causing the barcode to be scaled. The scaling is what was messing it up.

Comment: Do you happen to have a screenshot of which option it was? We have it set to another language and can't find any option that translates directly.